# Groovy integer filtering?

Tags: groovy

So in Groovy I am trying to figure a way to filter out any odd numbers and mixed numbers. I would also like to have it say "Even" when "a" is an even number. Values in "n" and "m" are replaceable. Where the "?" is, is where I need help. Here is the code right now:

```
n = ( 100 / 4 )

m = ( 6 * 6 )

a = (n + m)

println ( n + m )

println ( a / 2 )

if a = ?

{

        println "Even"

}
```

I am trying to get "a" to filter mixed numbers and odds out like the answer 30.5. I have looked and I can't find anyone that has made a way to do this.

When you run it, it says this:

```
groovy> n = ( 100 / 4 ) 

groovy> m = ( 6 * 6 ) 

groovy> a = (n + m) 

groovy> println ( n + m ) 

groovy> println ( a / 2 ) 

groovy> if a = ?

groovy> { 

groovy>     println "Even" 

groovy> } 

1 compilation error:

expecting '(', found 'a' at line: 6, column: 4
```

Any answers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you basically asking how to determine if a number is even or odd?

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
boolean isEvenInteger(Number value) {
  return new BigDecimal("$value").remainder(2) == 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another route would be:

```
if( a.toBigInteger().mod( 2 ) == 0 ) {
  println 'Even'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly threw this together to do something similar in test cases while keeping the code a little more literate...define the general class somewhere (unfortunate name but this was for quick test code):

```
@TupleConstructor
class NumClass {
    Closure<Boolean> test
    boolean isCase(Object o) { test(o) }
}
```

and then some instances to test against:

```
static final NumClass EVEN = new NumClass({!(it % 2)})
static final NumClass ODD = new NumClass({it % 2})
```

and then the classes could be tested against using `switch` or `in`

```
(1..20).findAll{it in ODD}

(1..20).each{
  switch(it) {
    case EVEN:
      println "${it} is even"
      break
    case ODD:
      println "${it} is odd"
      break
    default:
      println "${it} is a mystery to me"
  }
}
```